# Client to Client communication using select() function in c

Tags: c, sockets, select, client-server, ipc

I was trying to implement a client to client communication with a server in between them. The function of the server is that when a client suppose Client A sends a message to the server, the server should forward that message to the other client, Client B. Same way when the Client B sends a message to the server it should be forwarded to Client A. This programs involves only two clients.
The error I get when I execute the code is that it says:

```
Socket Operation on Non-socket
```

I get this error when the received message from Client A is forwarded to Client B. I think the issue is due to the storing of received address of Client B to the address of Client A. I'm not sure about that.

> My server code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define SERVER_PORT 5009


int main(){
unsigned int sockfd, c,c1,c2, clientlen, clientfd;
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_in client1;
int clientsocks[2];
char rmsg1[100], msg1[100],rmsg2[100], msg2[100];
char w_msg[] = "Connection to server established";

fd_set readfds; // For temp file descriptor list.

clientsocks[0] = 0 ;
clientsocks[1] = 0 ;
//Socket Creation Process.
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if( sockfd < 0){
    perror("Socket cannot be created");
}

//For reusing the socket.
int on = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0)
//Socket address
bzero((char *) &server, sizeof(server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4 internet Protocols
inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &server.sin_addr);
server.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

//Binding socket to address.
if (bind( sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof (server) ) < 0 ){
    perror("Bind Error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//Listen to accept connection.
if( listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN) < 0 ){
    perror("Error in Listen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

unsigned int new_sock;
clientlen =sizeof(client1);
int activity;
while(1){

    //Clear socket set.
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    //Adding main sockfd to the socket set.
    FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);
    unsigned int max_sd = sockfd;

    //Add child sockets to set.
    for(int i=0 ; i<2; i++){
           c = clientsocks[i];
        if(c > 0)
            FD_SET(c, &readfds);
        if(c > max_sd)
            max_sd = c;
    }

    activity = select(max_sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(activity < 0){
        perror("Error in select()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Incoming connection when something happens on sockfd.
    if( FD_ISSET(sockfd, &readfds)){
        new_sock = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client1, &clientlen);
        if(new_sock > 0){
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                if(clientsocks[i] == 0){
                    clientsocks[i] = new_sock;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(  new_sock < 0){
            perror("Error Accepting");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if( send(new_sock, w_msg, strlen(w_msg), 0) != strlen(w_msg)){
            perror("Welcome message");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    c1 = clientsocks[0];
    c2 = clientsocks[1];
    FD_SET(c1, &readfds);
    FD_SET(c2, &readfds);
    }

    //Else if its not a new incoming connection.
    if(FD_ISSET(c1, &readfds)){
        if(recv(c1, rmsg1, 100, 0) < 0){
            perror("Receive 1");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Client1 >> %s\n", rmsg1);
        //Forwarding to Client B.
        if( send(c2, rmsg1, 100, 0) < 0){
            perror("Error forwarding to 2");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(c2, &readfds)){
        if(recv(c2, rmsg2, 100, 0) < 0){
            perror("Receive 2");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Client2 >> %s\n", rmsg2);
        if( send(c1, rmsg2, 100, 0) < 0 ){
            perror("Error Forwarding to 1");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
close(sockfd);
return 1;
}
```

My problem involves two clients only. I would really appreciate if you could point out some other improvements also.

Comment: If you get an error it is not acceptable to let execution proceed as though it hadn't happened. Every one of those `perror()` calls should be followed by a cleanup and a return.

Comment: How do the client sockets get stored into `clientsocks`?

Comment: @EJP You mean I should break the loop and return?

Comment: @immibis I used the clientsocks[i] to store the socket descriptor of the incoming connections that is being accepted. But I'm not sure how to correctly store the incoming connection into the clientsocks array.

Comment: @VishnuNK "I used the clientsocks[i] to store the socket descriptor of the incoming connections that is being accepted" - great! But, **where** are you storing them in that array? Because I don't see it.

Comment: @immibis That's where I'm confused at. I tried using a for loop to store the new_sock fd after calling accept() function. But didn't help that much.     'for(i=0; i<2; i++){ clientsocks[i] = new_sock; }'

Comment: @VishnuNK Do you know how arrays work and how for loops work? It should be clear why `for(i=0; i<2; i++){ clientsocks[i] = new_sock; }` stores the new socket in both array slots.

Comment: @immibis In order to avoid rewriting the same array an if condition can be used right? I have edited the code. Please check.

Comment: @VishnuNK Check what?

Comment: What part of 'cleanup and return' don't you understand?

Comment: @immibis In order to store the new socket descriptors in different array slots I have used an if condition. I have edited the code in the question asked.

Comment: @EJP Does using exit(EXIT_FAILURE) helps?

Comment: @VishnuNK That doesn't answer my question. Check what?

Comment: @immibis The code I have edited. I have made some edits.

Comment: @VishnuNK I can see that. Check what?

Comment: @immibis I meant please go through the code and see whether the error you pointed out has been solved or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some structural problems that isn't really the job of StackOverflow members to fix.

1. Decide if each client is going to connect on the same socket or their own unique socket, listen accordingly.
2. If you have a shared connection, which it seems you are going for... and by shared connection I mean you are listening on one port and doing multiple accepts, then after a given accept you can't assume who has connected until you read some data from the port.   You should have each client send some information through, so that you know if A connected and then B or if B connected and then A.
3. The code around your setsockopt seems like you forgot {}
4. When saving the clientsocks you can use the information from the client to determine which array slot to use.   Maybe you have 100 clients and they each connect and then send a 32 bit word (which contains their client number, between 1-100).
5. Once you can read messages from various clients (probably want to print them out for now so you can see what is happening), you can build in various messages.   The goal is for client A to be able to ask the server for the contact information of client B so that A can directly connect to B and send B a message.
6. OR, instead of #5, Client 26 should be able to send a message to the server, indicating its is for client 45 and the server should be able to check the array of clients that have checked in and then send the message to the client in array slot 45.
7. Clients need to have unique ID/numbers so the server has a way to map the client ID's to clientarray sockets.
8. Some of those errors are better handled directly than causing the server to exit.   Maybe you can close the socket associated with the socket index causing the error.   Your error messages should indicate which client/socket index caused the error.   You, in general, need more debug messages and more information in the messages.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But its an awesome answer. Will take care of those things next time when I ask something.